# What is the proper way to handle maintenance mode in Laravel10?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

As title ask, I'm working a SPA backend api project, but since Larave 10 removed `MaintenanceModeException`, I wonder what's the proper way to handle maintenance mode in Laravel 10？

My old way handle the `MaintenanceModeException` is like：

```php
/**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e, $request) {
            if($request->is('api/*')) {
                switch(true)
                {
                    case $e instanceof MaintenanceModeException:
                        return (new SystemMaintenanceResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(503);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And now, Laravel 10 throw `HttpException` when in the maintenance mode, but `HttpException` contains not just the maintenance exception, there is no document about why remove the `MaintenanceModeException` and no new document about how to handle this in Laravel 10.

I need a specific response to tell the front end that I'm in maintenance mode, and I don't know how to tell exactly if I'm in maintenance mode right now because of Laravel removed the `MaintenanceModeException`.

What could I handle the maintenance mode correctly in Laravel 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days research, I end up with the solution below, it allowed me use the maintenance exception as before.

1. Create a custom exception

Create a custom exception by `php artisan make:exception MaintenanceModeException`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class MaintenanceModeException extends Exception
{
    protected $code = 50000;
    protected $message = "System maintenance.";
}
```

2. Edit the default middleware where Laravel handle the  maintenance mode, and overwrite the handle function.

Middleware path will be `app\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance`.

```php
use App\Exceptions\MaintenanceModeException;

class PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be reachable while maintenance mode is enabled.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->app->maintenanceMode()->active()) {
            $data = $this->app->maintenanceMode()->data();

            if (isset($data['secret']) && $request->path() === $data['secret']) {
                return $this->bypassResponse($data['secret']);
            }

            if ($this->hasValidBypassCookie($request, $data) ||
                $this->inExceptArray($request)) {
                return $next($request);
            }

            if (isset($data['redirect'])) {
                $path = $data['redirect'] === '/'
                            ? $data['redirect']
                            : trim($data['redirect'], '/');

                if ($request->path() !== $path) {
                    return redirect($path);
                }
            }

            if (isset($data['template'])) {
                return response(
                    $data['template'],
                    $data['status'] ?? 503,
                    $this->getHeaders($data)
                );
            }

            /* Origin will seems like this.
            throw new HttpException(
                $data['status'] ?? 503,
                'Service Unavailable',
                null,
                $this->getHeaders($data)
            );
            */

            // Overwrite with this part, force throw an exception when api routes.
            if($request->is('api/*') || $request->expectsJson())
                throw new MaintenanceModeException();
            else
                throw new HttpException(
                    $data['status'] ?? 503,
                    'Service Unavailable',
                    null,
                    $this->getHeaders($data)
                );
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

After it done, I can handle the system maintenance just I did before.

```php
$this->renderable(function (Throwable $e, $request) {
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        switch (true) {
            case $e instanceof ValidationException:
                return (new ValidationFailedResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(400);
            case $e instanceof AuthenticationException:
                return (new AuthenticationResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(401);
            case $e instanceof AuthorizationException:
            case $e instanceof UnauthorizedException:
                return (new AuthorizationResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(403);
            case $e instanceof NotFoundHttpException:
            case $e instanceof ItemNotFoundException:
            case $e instanceof ModelNotFoundException:
                return (new NotFoundResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(404);
            case $e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
                return (new MethodNotAllowResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(405);
            case $e instanceof ThrottleRequestsException:
                return (new ThrottleLimitResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(503);
            case $e instanceof MaintenanceModeException:
                return (new ExceptionResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(503);
        }

        /* ----- Unknown errors ----- */
        return (new ExceptionResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(500);
    }
});
```

The way can't handle system maintenance by `HttpException` is because of  the  `ThrottleRequestsException` also extend the `HttpException`, the condition `$e instanceof HttpException` will return true on it and also the http status code is also 503 on this exception.

As I known, there's more situation like these, for the api project, it seems must have to custom in Laravel 10, the default maintenance mode feature only design for web.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 10, the MaintenanceModeException has been removed, and instead, Laravel throws an HttpException with a status code of 503 when the application is in maintenance mode.

To avoid the issue of handling HttpException with a 503 status code, which may include other types of exceptions like TooManyRequestsHttpException, you can check if the application is in maintenance mode using the Illuminate\Foundation\Application instance.

Here's an example of how you can modify the exception handler to check for the maintenance mode using the application instance:

```
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 */
public function register(): void
{
    $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e, $request) {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            $app = $this->container->make(Application::class);
            if ($app->isDownForMaintenance()) {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'The application is currently in maintenance mode. Please try again later.'], 503);
            }
            if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Exceptions\MaintenanceModeException) {
                return (new SystemMaintenanceResponse($e))->response()->setStatusCode(503);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

We're first checking if the application is in maintenance mode using the isDownForMaintenance method of the Illuminate\Foundation\Application instance. If the application is in maintenance mode, we can return a JSON response with a specific message and a 503 status code.

If the application is not in maintenance mode and the thrown exception is an instance of MaintenanceModeException, we can return a custom response using your SystemMaintenanceResponse class, as in your original code.

This approach ensures that the correct response is returned when the application is in maintenance mode, regardless of the type of exception that was thrown.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answered, but as I said the `HttpException` is not contains only the maintenance mode, this will cause another issue which leads to incorrect reporting of maintenance status when the throttle limit is reached, this is because the `TooManyRequestsHttpException` is extend by `HttpException`.

Comment: I know I can handle the `TooManyRequestsHttpException` before the `HttpException`, but logically, maintaining message should take precedence over all responses.

Comment: Won't the api appear as if it were in maintenance mode even if it's just a regular/real 503 response in this case?! A dirty workaround for cases where you just want the handler to handle maintenance mode exceptions caused by artisans down command is to use the message switch and checking the message in the handler as well `php artisan down --status=418` `if ($e instanceof HttpException && $e-> getStatusCode() === 418)`

Comment: @Hockic Unfortunately, yes, after removed the `MaintenanceModeException` in Laravel 10, it seems just like a regular `HttpException`, even the error message not showing anything about if is maintenance mode caused.

Comment: @Charlie thanks for your clarification, I have updated my answer to avoid the issue of handling HttpException with a 503 status code. please try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Mehdi I've vote up your answered because it might give some inspiration or example to others. Also I'll keep the mark for a while to see if someone post a better way to do this.